# Angular animation with position fixed to bottom set to 0

Tags: angular, css-animations, angular-animations

I'm trying to perform an enter slide-in animation using angular animation library.

One of the child div is placed at bottom of page using `position: fixed, bottom: 0`

The problem how ever is that while animation starts the child div starts its position at top and after animation is finished moves down to bottom of page.

Following is the example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-motion-7aqxuf?file=app/app.module.ts).

As you observe is that child Box, Parent Box both end animation at same position, and after that child box moves down.

How to solve this issue so that when animation starts child div is at the bottom of the page.
Because of this animation doesn't look smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I played around a bit with your code and got this:

```
//our root app component
import { Component, NgModule, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';

import { style, animate, animation, animateChild, useAnimation, group, sequence, transition, state, trigger, query as q, stagger } from '@angular/animations';
const query = (s,a,o={optional:true})=>q(s,a,o);

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="appContainer" [@routeChange]>
      <div class="box">Parent box</div>
      <div class="box child" [@childElem]>Child box</div>
    </div>
  `,
  animations: [
    trigger('routeChange', [
      transition(':enter', [
        query('@*', [animateChild()]),
        query('.box', [
          style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 0 }),
          animate('3400ms cubic-bezier(.75,-0.48,.26,1.52)', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1 }))
        ])
      ]),
    ])
  ],
  styles: [`

    .appContainer {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }

   .child {
     color: green;
     bottom: 0;
     left: center;
     position: fixed;
   }

    .box {
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: #f0397b;
      margin: 5px;
    }


  `]
})
export class App {

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MatButtonModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-motion-mdf38y?file=app/app.module.ts) is the fork of your code on Stackblitz. I hope it helps :)